# Is pushing vectors back into vector UB?

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer

I have rather simple code but probably complex question.

```
std::vector<int> V;
///.. code that uses vector
V.push_back(V.back());
```

Is this call of `push_back` undefined behaviour?
The problem really relates the case when vector is full, will it reallocate and somehow invalidates or changes back?